# Метод Ньютона для системы нелинейных уравнений (C++ Builder)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Мои наработки программы, но она неправильно работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так в алгоритме и вообще?

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    x = StrToFloat(Edit1->Text);
    y = StrToFloat(Edit2->Text);
    z = StrToFloat(Edit3->Text);
    esp = StrToFloat(Edit4->Text);
    double a[n][n], a1[n][n], b[n], det, invdet, f[n],
           K[n]; //a[3][3]-матрица Якоби;
    //a1[3][3]-обратная матрица; b[3]-произведение а1[3] на f[3]; f[3]-массив функций; K[3]-массив переменных
    double xk, yk, zk, xn, yn, zn,
           max; //изменение значения переменных при k=0,1,2..
    int k = 0; //кол-во итераций
    //Матрица Якоби
    {
        a[0][0] = (-2 * x - 1);
        a[0][1] = (2 * z);
        a[0][2] = (2 * y);
        a[1][0] = (-3 * z);
        a[1][1] = (2 * y - 1);
        a[1][2] = (-3 * x);
        a[2][0] = (-2 * y);
        a[2][1] = (-2 * x);
        a[2][2] = (-2 * z - 1);
        //Определитель
        det = a[0][0] * a[1][1] * a[2][2] + a[0][1] * a[1][2] * a[2][0] +
              a[0][2] * a[1][0] * a[2][1] -
              a[0][2] * a[1][1] * a[2][0] - a[0][0] * a[1][2] * a[2][1] - a[0][1] *
              a[1][0] * a[2][2];
        invdet = 1 / det;

        //Обратная матрица
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                a1[0][0] =  a[1][1] * a[2][2] - a[1][2] * a[2][1] * invdet;
                a1[0][1] = -a[1][0] * a[2][2] + a[2][0] * a[1][2] * invdet;
                a1[0][2] =  a[1][0] * a[2][1] - a[1][1] * a[2][0] * invdet;
                a1[1][0] = -a[0][1] * a[2][2] + a[0][2] * a[2][1] * invdet;
                a1[1][1] =  a[0][0] * a[2][2] - a[0][2] * a[2][0] * invdet;
                a1[1][2] = -a[0][0] * a[2][1] + a[0][1] * a[2][0] * invdet;
                a1[2][0] =  a[0][1] * a[1][2] - a[0][1] * a[1][1] * invdet;
                a1[2][1] = -a[0][0] * a[1][2] + a[0][2] * a[2][0] * invdet;
                a1[2][2] =  a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[0][1] * a[1][0] * invdet;
            }
        }

        //Массив функций
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            f[0] = f1(x, y, z);
            f[1] = f2(x, y, z);
            f[2] = f3(x, y, z);
        }

        //Массив переменных
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            K[0] = x;
            K[1] = y;
            K[2] = z;
        }

        do {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    b[0] = a[0][0] * f[0] + a[0][1] * f[1] + a[0][2] * f[2];
                    b[1] = a[1][0] * f[0] + a[1][1] * f[1] + a[1][2] * f[2];
                    b[2] = a[2][0] * f[0] + a[2][1] * f[1] + a[2][2] * f[2];
                }
            }

            xk = K[0] - b[0];
            yk = K[1] - b[1];
            zk = K[2] - b[2];
            xn = xk - x;
            yn = yk - y;
            zn = zk - z;
            {
                if (abs(xn) > abs(yn))
                {
                    if (abs(xn) > abs(zn))
                    {
                        max = xn;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        max = zn;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (abs(yn) > abs(zn))
                    {
                        max = yn;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        max = zn;
                    }
                }
            }
            x = xk;
            y = yk;
            z = zk;
        } while (abs(max) >= esp);

        k++;
        Edit5->Text = FloatToStr(xk);
        Edit6->Text = FloatToStr(yk);
        Edit7->Text = FloatToStr(zk);
        Edit8->Text = FloatToStr(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Форматирование надо поправить, а то находящиеся на одном уровне 2 закрывающие фигурные скобки подряд выглядят вырвиглазно. Ещё неплохо было бы вынести логику в отдельную функцию, чтобы не смешивать логику и ввод-вывод данных (Edit5->Text=FloatToStr(xk))

Comment: ок, с этим понятно, спасибо
мне б понять, где в алгоритме ошибка(

Comment: @emrvs, если Вы хотите получить помощь, хорошо бы не заставлять других ломать глаза, как минимум. И описать проблему подробнее, а не ограничиваться фразой `она неправильно работает`. На каком наборе данных? Какой результат ожидается/получается? И т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что непонятно, зачем вы 9 раз (я думаю, `n` у вас определено выше как `const int n = 3`, так?) повторяете одни и те же вычисления?

```
//Обратная матрица
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
      a1[0][0]= a[1][1]*a[2][2]-a[1][2]*a[2][1]*invdet;
      a1[0][1]=-a[1][0]*a[2][2]+a[2][0]*a[1][2]*invdet;
      a1[0][2]= a[1][0]*a[2][1]-a[1][1]*a[2][0]*invdet;
      a1[1][0]=-a[0][1]*a[2][2]+a[0][2]*a[2][1]*invdet;
      a1[1][1]= a[0][0]*a[2][2]-a[0][2]*a[2][0]*invdet;
      a1[1][2]=-a[0][0]*a[2][1]+a[0][1]*a[2][0]*invdet;
      a1[2][0]= a[0][1]*a[1][2]-a[0][1]*a[1][1]*invdet;
      a1[2][1]=-a[0][0]*a[1][2]+a[0][2]*a[2][0]*invdet;
      a1[2][2]= a[0][0]*a[1][1]-a[0][1]*a[1][0]*invdet;
    }
}
```

Да еще к тому же и неверные? Разве обратная матрица вычисляется по таким формулам? Как минимум вы забыли о скобках; правильность индексов я не проверял.

Ну, а дальше и проверять пока не стал - раз сразу вычисления не те идут, то понятно, что что бы ни делалось дальше, толку не будет...

Comment: Очень было бы желательно попросить Вас либо давать переменным человеческие имена или сопровождать код комментариями. Иначе то, что Вы написали, выглядит вполне по школярски и разбору не подлежит. Неплохо было бы привести функции, корни которых Вы надеетесь найти.

Answer (score 0):

1. Определитель вычислен нормально.
2. invdet надо умножать на скобку с алгебраическим дополнением (Harry прав).
3. Есть ошибки и в алгебраических дополнениях, должно быть:
   `a[2][0] = ( a[0][1]*a[1][2]-a[1][1]*a[0][2])*invdet;`
   `a[2][1] = (-a[0][0]*a[1][2]+a[1][0]*a[0][2])*invdet;`
4. Если нужна помощь по функциям, то следует описать исходные данные и сам алгоритм (дать название и внятную ссылку).